# Django Querying: How do i query an account page through a blog post that the account owner has created? aka link from one to another

Tags: python, django, querying

Django Querying: How do i query an account page through a blog post that the account owner has created? aka link from one to another. So I have an account model and a blog post model, with the author as the foreign key. I am unsure of how i can do the querying of the account. Can anyone advise how this is normally done? Because I tried to do `user_id=request.user.id` but this would take me to my own account view. Thanks!

html

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'account:view'  %}">{{blog_post.author}}</a>
```

views.py

```
def detail_blog_view(request, slug):
    context = {}
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    context['blog_post'] = blog_post
    return render(request, 'HomeFeed/detail_blog.html', context)
```

urls.py for Blogs

```
path('<slug>/detail/', detail_blog_view, name= "detail"),
```

urls.py for accounts:

```
    path('<user_id>/', account_view, name="view"),
```

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email    = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
 title  = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
 body   = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
 slug   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
 author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to *query* the `author`, what you do is just get the `foreign key` value from the `BlogPost` object like this:

**views.py**

```
def post(request, pk):
    post = BlogPost.objects.get(pk=pk)
    author = post.author
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post,
                                         'author': author})
```

Then display it in a template:

**post.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'view' author.pk %}">{{ author }}</a>
(or you can use {{ post.author }} here aswell) says:
{{ post.title }} | {{ post.body }}
```

**EDIT**

in your urls where you have a path to your user profile you actually need to specify the argument type like:

```
path('<int:user_id>/', account_view, name="view"), # btw dont call your views 'view', name should describe what the view actually does or shows
```

Comment: Hi @SLDem, why is the int: in the url necessary? because for my whole project i did not include the int most of the time when i do the querying. Also, i cannot use that for my views.py because every post has a Slug, I have included the url for the post for your reference.

Comment: is there any way to not make major changes but be able to query that account? By inserting something into my html template only? thanks

Comment: show your template in the question please

Comment: if its a `slug` use `<str:slug>/` instead, read this to find out why its necessary https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/

Comment: hi @SLDem i have included the urls.py for the blog post. let me know what else you require. the template is basically the html code at the top^ which i have included..lol wasted 4 hours of today on this :(

Comment: your `url` accepts an attribute inside arrow brackets which is `<user_id>` right? So you need to actually pass that argument to it where you write your url in the template like this: `<a href="{% url 'accounts:view' blog_post.author.pk %}"> {{ blog_post.author }} </a>`

Comment: not sure what is your thinking process to derive this `blog_post.author.pk ` but it worked thank you bro!

Comment: well you are passing 1 item in the context to your view which is `blog_post`, it contains multiple fields including a `ForeignKey` to your `blog_post` instance `author`, with that `ForeignKey` you can access any data from the author object like `pk` (the one we used for the url), `email` and `username`, basically the fields you have in your `User Model`

Comment: I never had to use them so no, can't help you with that :)

Comment: Hi @SLDem if you are looking to answering another question, heres one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550279/django-html-how-can-i-allow-users-to-add-additional-input-fields-ensuring-they