# Django-HTML: How can i allow users to add additional input fields (ensuring they are not required)? Something like a + button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

Django-HTML: How can i allow users to add additional input fields (ensuring they are not required)? Something like a + button. I only want to display info 1. And only when users press the '+" button, these fields will appear and allow them to add info_2 and info_3. Is this possible? Because do i need to provide like an additional field in the model.py: eg `info_4 = ..... info_5` =.......

I have searched the Stackoverflow but was unable to find a question and answer very similar to this. Maybe someone can advice on the coding as i believe your input will be very beneficial to both django and html beginners:)

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
 title                  = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
 body                   = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
 info_1 = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=False, blank=False)
 info_2 = models.TextField(max_length=3000, null=False, blank=False)
 info_3 = models.TextField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
```

html:

```
  <form class="create-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
   <!-- chief_title -->
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_title">Chief Title!</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="chief_title" id="id_title" placeholder="Title" required autofocus>
   </div>

  <!-- Body -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_body">Full Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" type="text" name="body" id="id_body" placeholder="This is about..." required></textarea>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_Info_1">Info_1</label>
    <input class="form-control" rows="10" type="text" name="Info_1" id="id_Info_1" placeholder="Info_1..." required></input>
   </div>
```

forms.py

```
class CreateBlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['chief_title', 'body' , info_1' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a seprate `Model` called `Info` and add a ForeignKey relationship to a `post`, then the `post` author after its creation could add as many `info` objects as he would want.

Comment: Bro, then will the database table be affected? Because there’s no specified no. Of info columns.

Comment: Also, it won’t be possible in HTML because no matter what I’ve to use an <input> for every input that I put in. 

And for my forms.py form I’ve to specify the number of fields what. Or do I just need to specify one info field

Comment: Yes ofc, you will be able to manually add and remove as many fields as you want, each field will be tied to a specific post and you'll be able to access them all in a template

Comment: but what about the database? how do i made it such that they will auto-add a new column if there is extra data do you have an example code to show in your answer btw haha?

Comment: when you create your post inside the post view you can create a `InfoForm` or something like that to add info data and when submitting this form you will assign the `info` object to the post, then under the post if it has any `info` objects related you will simply display them

Comment: that is mighty kind of you mate, I will :)

Comment: Bro, I looked up the documentation and realised that django formsets might be able to address my issue. Let me try it out and get back to you via email. You can read if you’re interested :)  @SLDem https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/